# Bringing money to UK for investment purposes

Tags: taxes, united-kingdom, investing

What are the tax implications on bringing money from abroad to the UK for investment purposes. Specifically I'm considering starting a private limited company for a rental business, and also making a loan to an existing private limited company. The money was earned before moving to UK in the foreign country and was taxed there.

Comment: https://www.gov.uk/tax-support-for-overseas-businesses-investing-in-the-uk#more-like-this

Comment: Link above not working. Here's the corrected link: https://www.gov.uk/tax-support-for-overseas-businesses-investing-in-the-uk

Answer (score 2):

Transfers of money to the UK for any purpose are not generally taxed, so you can just transfer it here and invest.

Once the money is here, you'll be taxed on the business activity like anyone else - the company will have to pay corporation tax, and depending on your own residency you might have to pay income tax on any distributions from the company.